# Using modulo to loop 9-0 and printing

Tags: c, arrays, modulo

Currently I am having an issue in my program where I am trying to have a very basic encryption method that if 5 is entered, 9 is printed. I am trying to make it loop so that z will become d, and 9 will become 3. I have currently got it adding 4, but it is not doing the loop from 9-0 for integers, for letters it is working fine.

Below is a piece of code that is made from elements of my code to reproduce what is happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

int i, j;
char password[9];


printf("Please enter a password:\n\n");
scanf("%8c", &password);



for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(password[i] >= '0' && password[i] <= '9')
        {
            password[i] = (char)(password[i] + 4 % 10);
        }

        if((password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z') || (password[i] >= 'A' && password[i] <= 'Z') )
        {
            password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'a' + 4) % 26 + 'a');
        }
    }

    for(j =  0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", password[j]);
    }
```

}

Comment: `scanf("%8c", &password);` --> `scanf("%8s", password);`

Comment: @SouravGhosh `%8c` means "match exactly 8 characters", so I cannot tell that using `%8c` instead of `%8s` is wrong.

Comment: @MikeCAT and that is why I posted this as a _comment_.

Comment: @MikeCAT did I forget to mention about null termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle the numbers and the letters identically. You have:

```
        password[i] = (char)(password[i] + 4 % 10);
        ...
        password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'a' + 4) % 26 + 'a');
```

You need to subtract and add `'0'` for numbers, just like you do with `'a'` for letters:

```
        password[i] = (char)((password[i] - '0' + 4) % 10 + '0');
        ...
        password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'a' + 4) % 26 + 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

- `password[i] + 4 % 10` is always equals to `password[i] + 4` since the precedence of `%` is higher one of `+`.
- `scanf("%8c", &password);` causes undefined behavior due to type mismatch. Remove the `&` and write it as `scanf("%8c", password);`.
- You should deal with uppercase letters and lowercase letters separately because for example `'A' - 'a' + 4` becomes negative value if you use ASCII code and then the result will be what you won't want.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int i, j;
    char password[9] = "{0}";

    printf("Please enter a password:\n\n");
    scanf("%8c", password);

    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if(password[i] >= '0' && password[i] <= '9')
        {
            password[i] = (char)((password[i] + 4) % 10);
        }

        if(password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z')
        {
            password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'a' + 4) % 26 + 'a');
        }

        if(password[i] >= 'A' && password[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            password[i] = (char)((password[i] - 'A' + 4) % 26 + 'A');
        }
    }

    for(j =  0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", password[j]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Sorry new to using this language I thought you use & in scanf when you want to score the character written. Have changed it thanks for the help!